Is $x^4 + y^4$ irreductible in $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Let $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4$ . Descompose it as product of irreductible factors on $\Bbb{C}[x,y], \Bbb{R}[x,y]$ and $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$ .

If we denote $\omega:= e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$, it is clear that $$f(x,y) = \prod_{k=0}^3 (x+\omega^{2k+1}y) $$
which is a descomposition on $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ .
By notable identities: $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 = (x^2 + y^2)^2 - 2x^2 y^2 = (x^2 + y^2 + \sqrt{2} xy ) \cdot (x^2 + y^2 - \sqrt{2} xy) $ which is a descomposition on $\Bbb{R}[x,y]$
I am not seeing any descomposition for $f$ on $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$, I have tried several ways but I am not getting it. The problem is that, I neither see any way to show its irreductibility (in case it is) with any of the Criterions I know (Eisenberg, Cohn, Modular and Roots' Criterion) so any possible help would be appreciated.

A factorization over $\mathbb Q$ would also be a factorization over $\mathbb R$.

Well, since you know how it factors in $\mathbb{C}$, one approach could be to show that there is no non-trivial product of factors that lie in $ \mathbb{Q}$. So just check 14 (or 7) products.

@anankElpis Sorry but how does applies on this case? I said that I do not see a factorization on $\Bbb{Q}$

@CalvinLin I see, so it might be sufficient doing that, I will try, thanks!

@Superdivinidad If you could write $x^4+y^4$ as product of two quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x,y]$, wouldn't that factorisation also work in $\mathbb R[x,y]$? Thereby contradicting that $\mathbb R[x,y]$ is a UFD since you've found another factorisation of $x^4+y^4$ into product of quadratics.

@Nothingspecial Oh, I see, beautiful argument! Thanks

Another method which avoids working in $\Bbb R$ is to do a change of variable $x \mapsto x + y$ and then use Eisenstein criterion with $p = 2$.

Suppose, if possible, $x^4+y^4=p(x,y)\,q(x,y)$ for some degree $2$ polynomials $p,q$ in $\mathbb Q[x,y]$.
$\mathbb R[x,y]$ is a UFD and we have $x^4 + y^4 = (x^2 + y^2 + \sqrt{2} xy ) \, (x^2 + y^2 - \sqrt{2} xy)=p(x,y)\,q(x,y).\tag*{}$  WLOG assume that $p$ is an associate of $(x^2 + y^2 + \sqrt{2} xy )$ and $q$ is an associate of $(x^2 + y^2 - \sqrt{2} xy)$.
However, it's easy to check that there is no associate of $(x^2 + y^2 + \sqrt{2} xy )$ with all rational coefficients. We arrive at a contradiction. Thus, $x^4+y^4$ cannot be factored as product of two-degree polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x,y]$.
Now, let's try $x^4+y^4=p(x,y)\,q(x,y)$ where $p$ is a linear polynomial and $q$ is a degree three polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x,y]$.
Again in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ which is a UFD, there is no linear factor of $x^4+y^4$ which has an associate having all rational coefficients. So there is no linear polynomial $p\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ s.t. $p\mid (x^4+y^4)$. Again, a contradiction!
Now, conclude that $x^4+y^4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x,y]$.

$X^4+Y^4$ is irreducible if and only if the dehomogenization $X^4+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible (since $Y$ obviously doesn't divide $X^4+Y^4$). Since it is also $X^4+1 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ if and only of it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. This is the case.
